# Can I call a method with a field value in Java?

Tags: java, methods, call, field

Is is possible in Java to call a method based on a field value? For example, I ask the user what soda they want. They enter their selection and the value of the field that holds their selection is used to call the method.

Obviously the below code doesn't work. But I'm hoping it will illustrate my intent. Is this sort of thing even possible in Java?

The goal is to effectively switch without using IF or SWITCH statements.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FieldResolutionTest
{
     public static void main (String[] args)
     {
         Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
         MethodTester test = new MethodTester();

         System.out.println("Please enter ONE or TWO");
         String selection = inputScanner.nextLine();

         test.(selection)();
     }
}

public class MethodTester
{
     public void ONE()
     {
         System.out.println("You ran method ONE");
     }

     public void TWO()
     {
         System.out.println("You ran method TWO");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reflection. This is your example with minimal modifications:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FieldResolutionTest {
     public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
         Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
         MethodTester test = new MethodTester();

         System.out.println("Please enter ONE or TWO");
         String selection = inputScanner.nextLine();

         Method method = MethodTester.class.getMethod(selection);
         method.invoke(test);
     }
}

class MethodTester {
     public void ONE() {
         System.out.println("You ran method ONE");
     }

     public void TWO() {
         System.out.println("You ran method TWO");
     }
}
```

Of course, you need to add some error handling. For example, you should check that the user entered the name of one of the allowed methods, like this:

```
        Map<String, Method> methods = new HashMap<String, Method>();
        for (Method m: MethodTester.class.getMethods()) {
            methods.put(m.getName(), m);
        }

        if (methods.containsKey(selection)) {
            methods.get(selection).invoke(test);
        } else {
            System.err.println("No such method: " + selection);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, you very clearly explained to achieve what I was looking for, and how to implement it in my theory.

Answer (score 7):

It *is* technically possible with reflection, but if you have a finite number of known possible methods, it would be much simpler to use a switch statement (or `if`/`else` if you don't have Java 7):

```
switch (selection) {
    case "ONE":
        test.ONE();
        break;
    case "TWO":
        test.TWO();
        break;
    // etc.
    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid method!");
        break;
}
```

If the methods are dynamic or you are testing lots of classes, and you still want to go the reflection route, it would look something like this:

```
try {
    Method m = MethodTester.class.getMethod(selection);
    m.invoke(test);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
    System.out.println("Invalid method!");
}
```

Comment: @cyotee, found this one <http://www.java-forums.org/java-tip/6247-dynamic-method-calling.html>.

Answer (score 3):

A nice approach is with `enum`:

```
public class FieldResolutionTest
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter ONE or TWO");
    String selection = inputScanner.nextLine();

    FieldResolutionTest.valueOf(selection).run();
  }
}

public enum MethodTester
{
  ONE { public void run()
  {
    System.out.println("You ran method ONE");
  }},
  TWO { public void run()
  {
    System.out.println("You ran method TWO");
  }};

  public abstract void run();
}
```

Comment: What kind of complexity do you have in mind? Involves too much Java constructs? Since in terms of lines of code it's a rather concise approach.

Comment: Indeed, it is very concise and tidy. However, one should aim for code that is easy to read not to write.

Comment: Really, you see this as hard to read? Hm... I think much of it is familiarity. It's weird the first time, but soon grows in and you don't see anything difficult anymore. It's also the idiom promoted by Josh Bloch in Effective Java. An additional benefit is that you can have N methods resolved with the same amount of code, not just one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to test the input value and call the corresponding method:

```
if(selection.equals("ONE")) test.ONE();
else if (selection.equals("ONE")) test.TWO();
else System.out.println("Unknown input!");
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 7 was released, it is possible to perform the switch-case method on a string type variable

```
switch(selection) {
    case "ONE":
    test.ONE();
    break;

    case "TWO":
    test.TWO();
    break;
}
```

Again, only available since Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

As told by mellamokb you can use reflection to invoke the method. Typically the code will look like test.getClass().getMethod("ONE", null).invoke(..)